# Ruby convert string to method name of another class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The purpose is to store preferences of `TestApp` model into `MobileConfiguration` model with same name using migration.

Here is a migration:

```
TestApp.where.not(business_id: nil).each do |test_app|
  configuration = MobileConfiguration.find_or_initialize_by(business_id: test_app.business_id)
  MobileConfiguration::DISCLAIMERS.each { |disclaimer| test_app.public_send(disclaimer) }
  configuration.max_store_distance_radius = test_app.max_store_distance_radius
  configuration.save
end
```

`MobileConfiguration::DISCLAIMERS.each { |disclaimer| test_app.public_send(disclaimer) }` should store the test_app data into mobile_configuration.

`DISCLAIMERS` is an array of Model `MobileConfiguration`.

```
MobileConfiguration::DISCLAIMERS = [:app_disclaimer, :upgrade_disclaimer, :game_disclaimer]
```

`:app_disclaimer, :upgrade_disclaimer, :game_disclaimer` are preferences in `MobileConfiguration` Model

```
preferences(:configurations) do
  preference_group "Disclaimer" do
    string :app_disclaimer
    string :game_disclaimer
    string :upgrade_disclaimer
  end
end
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: @Surya I am trying to store the values of the 3 disclaimers in TestApp to MobileConfiguration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[MobileConfiguration::DISCLAIMERS].each do |property|
  configuration.public_send("#{property}=",test_app.public_send(property))
 end
```

can be used to copy values from one model to another for preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Using public_send with one attribute just calls that method. You need to use another attribute to pass some data into the method. Also you need to call the setter to pass data in. So:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end

foo = Foo.new

foo.public_send 'bar' # Just returns the current value of @bar - so nil.

foo.public_send 'bar=', 'something' # calls the setter and passes in 'something'

foo.public_send 'bar' # Now returns 'something'
```